# Using position is good practice or not

Tags: css, css-position

Can someone please guide me whether using positioning in css is good practice or not and will it creates problem when we are working on responsive design...

Comment: You mean e.g. position: relaive,absolute,sticky?

Comment: Ya example - position:relative; left:2px; etc

Comment: Of course, it is really neccessary sometimes, it really depends on what you are doing and where. There is a chance that a setting crashes your layout but in general these settings are useful and needed in layout. If you provide your code or specify your question I can give better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this explained in detail:

> https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/rwd-can-we-use-position-absolute-or-fixed-in-responsive/

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary in some cases.

```
position: relative; // relative position of the parent.
```

`position: relative` gives the default behavior of the element. However, it is required if you want to have child element with `position: absolute;` in order to have specific position inside. Otherwise, the child element will position with any closest parent with `position` attribute.

```
position: absolute; // absolute position of the parent
```

`position: absolute;` needs its parent to have position attribute, too. Otherwise, `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` attributes will have unexpected results.

```
position: fixed; // fixed position of the document
```

`position: fixed;` stays at fixed position in the document.

`z-index` won't have effect if you don't have `position` attribute.